# How to form a definite integral of two independent variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

**I have a dependent variable which is $$ W = |X - Y| $$ X and Y are independently distributed where $ X \sim Uniform(0,1)$ and $ Y \sim Uniform(0,2)$
What am I supposed to do is find the probability of $W <= 0.5 $**

I have split the function to two case one being $ X > Y$ and the other $ Y > X $ so I can define two functions for Y one is being $ Y = W + X$ for $Y > X$ and the other being $ Y = X - W$  for $ X > Y$. And then I tried to write down the integrals.

**Trial 1:**

$$\int_0^{0.5} \int_x^{x+w} \int_0^y dx\frac{dy}{2}dw$$ for $Y > X$ and
$$\int_0^{0.5}\int_y^{y+w} \int_0^x \frac{dy}{2}dxdw$$ for $X > Y$

When I evaluate these integrals and sum them, the answer comes out as a function of Y and X since it is far from being definite as I have not been provided with any X or Y values.

**Trial 2:**

Then I thought that maybe I should use $\int_x^{x+0.5}dy$ instead of $\int_0^{0.5}\int_x^{x+w}dydw$ which I still cannot understand why they give different values.

Then my function became

$$\int_x^{x+0.5} \int_0^y dx\frac{dy}{2}$$ for $Y > X$ and
$$\int_y^{y+0.5} \int_0^x \frac{dy}{2}dx$$ for $X > Y$

which led me to oppose the same problem now I cannot think of an alternative solution to this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are X and Y independent of one another?

Comment: @confusedStudent yes they are independently distributed random variables sorry for missing this information

Comment: Cross-post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/509382/119261.

Comment: I have provided [that answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/509433/250208)to my cross-post.